# Convert string to HTML element using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, string

I have a string like this:

```
i1:1,i3:5,i2:5
```

How can I convert it to a HTML element like this using pure JavaScript or jQuery?

```
<ul>
  <li id="i1" value="1"></li>
  <li id="i3" value="5"></li>
  <li id="i2" value="5"></li>
</ul>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
document.write('<ul>i1:1,i3:5,i2:5</ul>');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the initial string on the comma, then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the resulting array. On each iteration of `map` you can then split on the colon, and return a HTML string. You just need to make sure you [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array that `map` returns into a new string before you add it to the DOM.

```js
const str = 'i1:1,i3:5,i2:5';

const result = str.split(',').map(el => {
  const [key, value] = el.split(':');
  return `<li id="${key}" value="${value}">${value}</li>`;
}).join('');

const ol = document.querySelector('ol');
ol.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<ul>${result}</ul>`);
```

```html
<ol />
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: PS: `value` is an absolutely [*valid* attribute on a `OL > LI` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attr-value), reintroduced in HTML5 - **but only valid in the scope of an `<ol>` (Ordered List) parent.**

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
function createUlListByString(myString) {
    var elements = myString.split(',');
    var ul = $('<ul>');
    
    elements.forEach(function(item) {
        item = item.split(':');
        var li = $('<li id="' + item[0] + '" value="' + item[1] +'">'+ item[1] + '</li>');
        ul.append(li);
    });
    
    return ul;
}

var ul = createUlListByString('i1:1,i3:5,i2:5');
```

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
function createUlListByString(myString) {
    var elements = myString.split(',');
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    
    elements.forEach(function(item) {
        item = item.split(':');
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.id = item[0];
        li.value = item[1];
        ul.append(li);
    });
    
    return ul;
}

var ul = createUlListByString('i1:1,i3:5,i2:5');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that my simple solution using method `forEach()` and method `split()` will not be superfluous, which will split the string into an *id* and a *value* taken from an array of similar data.

```js
let ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(ul);

["i1:1", "i3:5", "i2:5"].forEach(function (li) {
    let id_value = li.split(":");
    ul.innerHTML += "<li id=" + id_value[0] + ">" + id_value[1] + "</li>";
});

console.log(ul.outerHTML);
```